# kivy iOS deployment error

Tags: python, ios, kivy

I'm trying to use tornado in my kivy application. On Linux and Mac it works fine, however on iOS tornado is not getting imported.

```
2013-07-21 16:50:11.862 application[818:907] [Springtomize]: Loading into sb-external process

2013-07-21 16:50:12.868 application[818:907] PythonHome is: /var/mobile/Applications/B621455C-94BF-4AA7-97A3-B051F090C68A/application.app

2013-07-21 16:50:12.873 application[818:907] Initializing python

2013-07-21 16:50:13.232 application[818:907] Running main.pyo: /var/mobile/Applications/B621455C-94BF-4AA7-97A3-B051F090C68A/application.app/YourApp/main.pyo

[INFO              ] Kivy v1.7.1

[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 144 symbols loaded

[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=Nones

[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60s

[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=Nones

[DEBUG             ] [Image       ] option <dds> ignored by config

[DEBUG             ] [Image       ] option <pygame> ignored by config

[DEBUG             ] [Image       ] option <pil> ignored by config

[DEBUG             ] [Image       ] option <gif> ignored by config

[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_imageio, img_tex (img_dds, img_pygame, img_pil, img_gif ignored)

[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60s

[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600s

[DEBUG             ] [Text        ] Ignored <pygame> (import error)

[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: sdlttf(['text_pygame'] ignored)

 Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "/Users/0/Desktop/kivy-ios/app-application/YourApp/main.py", line 31, in <module>

 **ImportError: No module named tornado.ioloop**

2013-07-21 16:50:14.449 application[818:907] Application quit abnormally!

2013-07-21 16:50:14.496 application[818:907] Leaving
```

How to properly include modules when building with kivy and deploying on iOS?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://pyobjus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) might help? Let me know if it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include all the python module you want within your application. Remember, you did something like `pip install` or `easy_install` for tornado ? Then you need to include yourself into your project.

(this will change one day, when kivy-ios will be able to install pure-python module into the toolchain, as python-for-android does.)

Comment: How specifically does one add the python module into the application?